# How do I incorporate SCA data into the Paypal DoDirectPayment API call for PDS2

Tags: django, authentication, paypal

Paypal are hounding me to change my current payment gateway that uses their API, and hand it over to a third party (that presumably will charge for the service) because of the [PDS2](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/psd2) (Payment Service Directive - revised) which demands Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) unless a transaction is exempt. The extra info can be a password, fingerprint or phone, but details on how to use their API for this are missing.

Paypal's documentation is close to useless, but Stripe's documentation have information as to what constitutes an exempt transaction, and in fact that the PDS2 only applies if the business AND the customer's bank is in the European Economic Area (ref: https://stripe.com/en-nl/guides/strong-customer-authentication) and that the bank deems the transaction as risky.

The definition of a risky transaction is subjective and decided by the banks, so the implication is that we MUST enable SCA. I use django-paypal which provides helper functions and data structures for using paypal's API.

Paypal are not too good at supporting developers, and communication with their technical staff is impossible. So I emailed the developer of django-paypal, but I have not received a response (https://github.com/appsumo/django-paypal-1).

The deadline for this is September 2019, after which paypal warn of declined transactions and general pestilence if there is non-compliance with PDS2. The odd thing is, SCA was also introduced as a version 1 (PDS) back in 2015, and there were warnings of declined transactions then too.

For credit card, I currently use django-paypal `doDirectPayment` which uses paypal's DoDirectPayment which uses SOAP. I don't see anything in the doc about supplying credentials for SCA with these methods. I assume that I don't need to do anything extra for redirected paypal payments, as paypal control this payment process.

**UPDATE**
Paypal have consigned [Cardinal Commerce](https://cardinaldocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CC/pages/131806/Getting+Start) to provide some kind of API, BUT this is client side only using Songbird.js. They indicate there is a serverside solution though...

> Because Songbird is a client side JavaScript library it can only
>   interact with payment brands client side. Any interactions that
>   require server side implementations, such as our Cardinal Cruise
>   Hybrid integration, are out of scope for Songbird.js and the merchant
>   may need to integrate directly to the Cardinal Centinel platform
>   directly.

Comment: Hi, Did you get anything ?

Comment: Nope. I have to implement a Braintree solution